How to force all TMP UI objects to render together to avoid breaking the batching for UI?
I’m using TMP pro UI.
When using an sprite atlas, I noticed TMP objects are breaking batching because they use a different material.
Is there any easy solution to force them all to render together before or after everything else? They are pretty much on top of everything else.
I can’t put them close together in one parent, because they belong to different prefabs. That’d not be a solution for me.
Also I tried setting the same z-index for them, hoping them to render together. Didn’t work.
